# Why ipa of universal app is 300 mb?

Tags: ios, xcode5, ipa, ios-universal-app

I've build a universal app. On OS X file system XCode project with all resources and submodules take about 100 mb, but when I generate ipa file for ad-hoc deployment I get 300 mb file.
Several months ago when I had standalone iPad app, ipa was at most 15 mb. 
Is it something to do with settings?

Comment: Look in the ipa file and see what is so big.

Comment: thanks! "Test" files, lots of them went into archive!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found a problem. Lots of pdfs (for testing) went into archive. Thanks to @rmaddy! I should have paid more attention.